# How to remove paragraph marks with different format in MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have some lines that are separated by paragraph marks, but actually they belong to the same paragraph.

The issue is the text is in Arial 15, italic, but some words are not italic (shown in red) and the paragraph marks are Arial 15 italic, not italic and even Calibri 11. This means, not all paragraph mark have the same format.

I want to replace the paragraph marks with a space " " in order to join the lines in a single paragraph only for those group of continues lines that are Arial, 15 italic
even though thet have not italic within them.

I tried so far:

Find what: ^p (with format: Arial 15, Italic)
Replace with: " "

But doing this only finds the paragraph mark shown in green.

Below the image of input format and what I'm trying to get as output. Additionally I attach a sample file [Sample.docx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zufgmr08y4xo04/smp-1.docx?raw=1).

[image: Sample Image]
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReplacePara()
Dim Para As Paragraph, Xstr As String, Rng As Range
Dim i As Long, ln As Long
Dim PrvChrSize As Integer, NextChrSize  As Integer
Dim PrvChrFont As String, NextChrFont  As String
Dim PrvChrItalic As Boolean, NextChrItalic As Boolean

    With ActiveDocument
    For i = .Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set Para = .Paragraphs(i)
    ln = Para.Range.Characters.Count

        If ln > 1 Then
            With Para.Range.Characters(ln - 1).Font
            PrvChrSize = .Size
            PrvChrFont = .Name
            PrvChrItalic = .Italic
            End With

            If i < .Paragraphs.Count Then
                With .Paragraphs(i + 1).Range.Characters(1).Font
                NextChrSize = .Size
                NextChrFont = .Name
                NextChrItalic = .Italic
                End With
            Else
            NextChrSize = 0
            NextChrFont = ""
            NextChrItalic = False
            End If
        End If

        Debug.Print i, PrvChrSize, PrvChrFont, NextChrSize, NextChrFont
        If (PrvChrSize = 15 And (PrvChrFont = "Arial" Or PrvChrItalic = True)) _
        And (NextChrSize = 15 And (NextChrFont = "Arial" Or NextChrItalic)) Then
        Para.Range.Characters(ln).Text = " "
        End If
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Result from sample file:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmed Thanks for your help. Your solution outputs almost the output I'm looking for. It produces the correct output for first group of lines between Header 1 and Header 2 (those are Italic), but is removing the paragraph mark from the lines below of Header 2 (those are not Italic). I only want to remove the Para marks from group of lines that are Arial 15 and Italic and if some words in the middle of the group of Italics aren´t Italic (like those I shown in red), then don´t change their format. I hope make sense.

Comment: What i understand (may be wrong) then hope replacing the `Or` before  `PrvChrItalic` & `NextChrItalic` with `And` will do. Please feed back then only i will edit the Answer.

Comment: Ahmed, it seems to work in the sample file as you said, changing the "or" by "and". I understand your code analizes character by character, because in my real file is stuck for almost 10 min and I had to stop it. The file is about 2.2 MB and it has 2.1K pages, 871K words, 4,6M characters including spaces. So, I don´t know if it stucks or if it will take more than 10 min to finish hehe

Comment: Ger Cas,the code loops by paragraphs only and checks only last but one character for checking font etc. What ever that may be,it is real difficult foresee how it would perform on a real file. lets have think out some workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The document has about 4.2K paragraphs in case it matters.

Comment: Still could not find ways to boost performance to handle that Giant document.and posted code in code review. May please the follow the [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/222940/how-to-efficiently-loop-through-paragraphs-and-make-simple-changes-with-word-vba)

Comment: Fine Ahmed. Thanks a lot for your help and time. I'll check the link you kindly shared.

Comment: @Ger Cas Hope you have already been completed your task by splitting the document. Sorry to be late but come to some workable solution. Please check the Link to Code review for the solution.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Is very very appreciated that take your time to help.  I´m still didn´t complete my task regarding the question in this post. So, your efforts are not in vane. I tested with the sample file and works perfect. Then I tested with the real file, that this time have "Times New Roman" instead of "Arial" and size 14 instead of 15. I did the changes in your code for that but I got error after 2 min aprox `Subscript out of range` and when I debug I see that `i=42935` and in InmediateWindow the last value printed says `42000/42934` then `paragraph to delete:0` Thanks again.

Comment: If `DelCnt` is 0 that means `If (ChrSize = 15 And ChrFont = "Arial" And ChrItalic)        And (PrvChrSize = 15 And PrvChrFont = "Arial" And PrvChrItalic) Then` condition never satisfied within the whole document. Pl check out for that. If font is not in italics, make `ChrItalic=False` and `PrvChrItalic=False`.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. The error is in line `For i=Ubound(RngArr) to 1 Step -1`

Comment: That again confirm my suspect that the font size,name & italics combination is failed to satisfy. Check out in this direction.  another point, Code used to test only last character before paragraph marks. if that,s not the case may modify  1 with 2 or 3  in lines`If ln > 1 Then`  and : `With Para.Range.Characters(ln - 1).Font`

Comment: if you have the multiple files with different Font sizes etc. May add this code before `tm=Timer`. Add `Dim FntName As String, FntSize As Integer, FntItalic As Boolean
With Selection.Font
FntName = .Name
FntSize = .Size
FntItalic = .Italic
End With
If MsgBox(FntName & vbCrLf & FntSize & vbCrLf & FntItalic & vbCrLf, vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub`  and use thses variables in the conditional statement. Select at least a letter in desired paragraphs and run the code.

Comment: Hi Ahmed. Thanks a lot for your help. I checked the code and added the code you suggest for multiple files with different fonts. This time running the code on the same file of 4.2K paragraphs, the execution time was 91.24 seconds!!! Thanks for your kindly help, efforts and time you put in this case. God bless you for help people you don´t know.

Comment: Welcome @Ger Cas now you finally made my day. Also Many thanks for A Real Good Question with lot of challenges.